# How to test whether two RAW files have identical contents (but potentially different tags)?

Tags: raw

If I have two RAW files, how I can test whether they are indeed the same but with merely different tags?

(By "the same" I mean "the same data from the sensor".)

If it matters, the format I'm thinking about is ARW.

Answer (score 3):

Use [dcraw](https://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/) with the `-D` option to extract just the non-interpolated pixel data from each file. This will result in a `.pgm` file — a grayscale map — which you can then compare (using them `cmp` command in Linux for bytewise compare, or by making a checksum, or whatever else). I think this should be exactly what you want, since all metadata is discarded, and the format is [very simple](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html).

It's possible that two different programs which generate pgm files would use a slightly different format resulting in a different output (since there can be whitespace and comments), but I'm pretty sure that the results from dcraw will have nothing that varies other than actual differences in image data.

Comment: Slightly confused. If I get back a grayscale map, what happens to the color data...? (I probably misunderstood what you're saying.)

Comment: Interesting approach... I took the question as just wanting to determine if both files were generated from the same file, but with metadata changed by software. If it's really the image data you want to compare, this makes sense. Would it be possible for the gamma correction to mask some differences, though?

Comment: @Mehrdad It's a raw file. There is no color data as such. This outputs the value of each photosite completely disregarding the bayer (or whatever!) filter.

Comment: @junkyardsparkle I don't think so. From the dcraw docs, _By default, dcraw writes PGM/PPM/PAM with 8-bit samples, a BT.709 gamma curve, a histogram-based white level, and no metadata._ I guess could add `-W` to fix the white level, but for the same image the histogram-based approach should always give the same reasult.

Comment: If you _do_ want interpolated results, you could use `-h` or one of the various `-q` options instead of `-D`. The practical result will really be the same, assuming (and I am) that the algorithms used are deterministic.

Answer (score 2):

I grabbed the NEX-3 RAW sample from [here](http://rawsamples.ch/index.php/en/sony), made a copy of it, and ran [md5sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum) on both: same checksum. I then used [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to add a Subject tag to the test copy:

```
 exiftool -subject="testing 123" test_copy.ARW
```

and did the checksum again, different this time. I then ran

```
 exiftool -all= *.ARW
```

to remove all tags, and again generated checksums. They once again matched. This should be applicable to your situation, using any binary checksum utility. Make sure you work on *copies* of the files you're testing - exiftool makes backups by default, but you shouldn't rely on this.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to compare the images in Photoshop:

1. Load both images into Photoshop, using the same raw conversion settings.
2. Copy and paste one, so you end up with them as two layers on the same document. You can then flick between the two by toggling the top layer's visibility to pick up any significant differences.
3. Change the blend mode on the top layer to "Difference". That will  give you black pixels where the two layers are identical.
4. A brightness or curves adjustment will help you spot subtle differences.

I'm sure you could do something similar in any decent image editing program.

You could also try using [some sort of file comparison tool that can handle binary files](http://winmerge.org/) on the raw files themselves, but interpreting the results could be tricky.

Comment: This doesn't help. I'm looking to see if there are *any* differences, not just *visible* differences. And binary comparison doesn't help either, it's not like people memorize the specifications of each RAW format they handle...

Comment: You could always write a custom piece of software for the task, if that's what you really need.

Comment: @Mehrdad provided you work in a 16-bit space this ought to work - any changes you make to a 14-bit RAW file will show up in a 16-bit conversion. You can make any binary difference visible by using the levels/curves tool. The only downside to this is that some RAW converters discard edge pixels so the image you get is marginally smaller than the actual number of pixels on the sensor.